# SQL concatenate duplicate values based on a reference key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

```
col A  | Col B
--------------
   a   |  1   
--------------
   a   |  2   
--------------
   b   |  1  
--------------
   b   |  3  
--------------
   c   |  1
```

and I am basically looking for an SQL Query that produce the following output

```
col A  | Col B
--------------
   a   |  "1:2"   
--------------
   b   |  "1:3"  
--------------
   c   |  "1"
```

It must be a very simple query, but I just can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: What version of Oracle? LISTAGG is the natural solution, but it is only available since version 11.2. For the proper syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ListAgg()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function to aggregate string results:

```
 SELECT colA, '"' || ListAgg(colB, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colb) || '"'
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY colA;
```

`ListAgg()` takes the column we are aggregating as the first parameter and the delimiter character(s) as the second parameter. We just concatenate those beginning and ending double quotes to the ListAgg result to get the final result you are looking for.

Comment: In Oracle, this solution won't compile (incorrect syntax). LISTAGG is missing the mandatory key words WITHIN GROUP and the order_by clause.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't add the rest of the required mumbo jumbo in there. I had my head stuck on MySql's Group_Concat() function which doesn't need a `WITHIN GROUP` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working with my version of Oracle (11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit )
Could you please additional information how to do it in other DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL) ? It might be helpful for others.

Comment: It's different for each DBMS. Some have built in string agg functions, and others you have to resort to a Recursive CTE to pull it off. I'm 100% certain that there are probably dozens of answers for each DBMS already here on SO. It's a tricky thing to search for since, if you've never done it, you may not think of a great search term for it.